# Is Pages gone on iPad OS?

Tags: ipad, pages

I just updated my iPad to the latest verision of the operating system (iPad OS).

It seems that the Pages app is gone... and I can't install it.

AppStore displays a message on the Pages app:

> Pages is only available on macOS.

How to install Pages back on my iPad? I loved the sync with the other devices and everything and now this is a bit frustrating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Pages is not gone from iPadOS and iOS. Pages has a separate app for both macOS and iPadOS/iOS.

To download Pages for iPadOS, search for Pages on the App Store app on your iPad, or open the following link:

- [Pages on the App Store](https://apps.apple.com/app/pages/id361309726#?platform=ipad)

Comment: Yes, after running the post-install updates, Pages was installed. :) Thanks!